# How can I tell Firefox to ignore "cursor:" entrys in stylesheets?

Tags: firefox, css, cursor

Sometimes websites ([example](http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/)) cause Firefox to not switch the mouse cursor to a I-beam shape when pointing at (perfectly selectable) text.  I'm fairly certain this is the result of `cursor: default;` in the offending page's stylesheet.  How can I tell Firefox to ignore this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to change Firefox's `chrome.css` (or whatever the file is) so I settle for a bookmarklet (or just type this in): `javascript:void(document.body.style.cursor = "auto");`

Comment: It works. (I stuck it in a greasemonkey script for "*".)

Comment: Update: CSS file is `~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default/chrome/userContent.css`, added `body { cursor: auto !important; }`. Still nice to know how to monkeypatch styles from javascript though, so thanks!